# How do I prevent a guice module from being used?

Tags: playframework, guice

How do I prevent Guice from configuring this module in a test?

```
class SnsModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val snsClient: AmazonSNSAsyncClient = AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().build().asInstanceOf[AmazonSNSAsyncClient]
    bind(classOf[AmazonSNSAsyncClient]).toInstance(snsClient)
  }
}
```

I tried overriding the module:

```
  private val snsModule = new AbstractModule{
    override def configure(): Unit = {
      val snsClient: AmazonSNSAsyncClient = mock[AmazonSNSAsyncClient]
      bind(classOf[AmazonSNSAsyncClient]).toInstance(snsClient)
    }
  }

  override implicit lazy val app: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(new TestJwkModule(),  snsModule).build()
```

However `configure()` in `SnsModule` is still called, which is a problem because in my test environment an Exception is thrown by `AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

`disable` prevents the module from being loaded, eg:

```
override implicit lazy val app: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder().
   disable(classOf[SnsModule])
   overrides(snsModule).build()
```